# Gnome-control-center fails to open in 17.10

Tags: 17.10, gnome-control-center

After moving the docking bar from the left side of the screen to the bottom of the screen, gnome-control-center no longer opens on screen. It appears in the the list of processes and also as an icon on the docking bar but nothing opens on screen.

Comment: Can anyone help me here? I've purged gnome-control-center (apt-get purge) and re-installed it (apt-get install) with no change.

Comment: Fixed after re-installing 17.10